# Aggregating SHAP values obtained from different models?

Tags: shapley-value

I have SHAP values for two models (sklearns's GradientBoostingClassifier and RandomForestClassifier). They are positively correlated. Rank correlation (r_s) between the SHAP values of the two models is ~0.6. This correlation is much higher for the top features (~0.9).

Because the results for the two models are very much the similar, for the sake of avoiding redundancy while visualizing the SHAP values of the two models (e.g. using force plot etc.), I wonder if it would be possible to aggregate the SHAP values, in some way, across the two models. I wonder if this is something that is done conventionally (?).

Comment: To the same degree as you can mix pizza and ice cream in a blender for an aggregated meal...

Comment: So it is not possible. Good to know. Thanks.